# Determine batch size during `tensorflow.keras` Custom Class `call` method

Tags: keras, custom-layer

I'm building a custom keras Layer similar to an example found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object).  I want the `call` method inside the class to be able to know what the `batch_size` of the `inputs` data flowing through the method is, but the `inputs.shape` is showing as `(None, 3)` during model prediction.  Here's a concrete example:

I initialize a simple data set like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model

# Create fake data to use for model testing
n = 1000
np.random.seed(123)
x1 = np.random.random(n)
x2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=n)
x3 = np.random.lognormal(0, 1, size=n)

X = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([
    np.reshape(x1, (-1, 1)),
    np.reshape(x2, (-1, 1)),
    np.reshape(x3, (-1, 1)),
], axis=1))
```

Then I define a custom class to test/show what I'm talking about:

```py
class TestClass(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(TestClass, self).get_config()
        return config

    def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor):
        if inputs.dtype.base_dtype != self._compute_dtype_object.base_dtype:
            inputs = tf.cast(inputs, dtype=self._compute_dtype_object)

        print(inputs)
        print(f'inputs.shape = {inputs.shape}')

        return inputs
```

Then, when I create a simple model and force it to do a forward pass...

```py
input_layer = layers.Input(3)
test = TestClass()(input_layer)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00025)
model = Model(input_layer, test)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
model.predict(X.loc[:9, :])
```

... I get this output printed to the screen

```
model.predict(X.loc[:9, :])
Tensor("model_1/Cast:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)
inputs.shape = (None, 3)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step
Out[34]: 
array([[ 0.5335418 ,  0.7788839 ,  0.64132416],
       [ 0.2924202 , -0.08321562,  0.412311  ],
       [ 0.5118007 , -0.6822934 ,  1.1782378 ],
       [ 0.03780456, -0.19350041,  0.7637337 ],
       [ 0.86494124, -3.196387  ,  4.8535166 ],
       [ 0.26708454, -0.49397194,  0.91296834],
       [ 0.49734482, -1.6618049 ,  0.50054324],
       [ 0.8563762 ,  0.7956695 ,  0.29466265],
       [ 0.7682351 ,  0.86538637,  0.6633331 ],
       [ 0.85322225,  0.868021  ,  0.1776046 ]], dtype=float32)
```

You can see that during the `model.predict` call the `inputs.shape` prints out a value of `(None, 3)`, but obviously that's not true since the `call` method returns an output with a shape of `(10, 3)`.  How can I capture the `10` value in this example while in the `call` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can see *an* answer that helps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74323570/determine-batch-size-during-tensorflow-keras-custom-class-call-method).  However, in practice I used this simple function inside the `call` method to help get the tensorflow shape

```
import tensorflow as tf
from typing import Tuple

def get_tf_shape(inputs: tf.Tensor) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, ...]:
    shape = tf.shape(inputs)
    return tuple(shape[i] for i in range(len(shape)))
```

Here's the start of the `call` method:

```
def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor):
    shape = get_tf_shape(inputs)
    ...
```